# Inputs are not right-aligned

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the inputs of my study to be right-aligned.
The example I'm using is the [Delta Volume Columns Pro [LucF]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/) script by [LucF](https://www.tradingview.com/u/LucF/) from [PineCoders](https://www.pinecoders.com/).
However, my inputs are not right-aligned, and I don't see the difference with the example script.

The input section of my script is this:

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", overlay=true)

// ———————————————————— Inputs
// {
ER0 = "Absolute", ER1 = "Relative", ER2 = "Manual"
SW0 = "Off", SW1 = "On"

_00                         = input(true,   "════════════ General ═════════════")
i_gen_showDirectionLabels   = input(SW0,    "Direction",                                options = [SW0, SW1])
_10                         = input(true,   "════════════ Cur ses ═════════════")
i_cur_extendDP              = input(false,  "Extend post open")
i_cur_showErrorDP           = input(false,  "Show err")
_15                         = input(true,   "════════════ His ses ═════════════")
_20                         = input(true,   "════════════ Errors ══════════════")
i_err_type                  = input(ER0,    "Error type",                               options = [ER0, ER1, ER2])
_20_00                      = input(true,   "════════════ Manual ══════════════")
i_err_man_high              = input(10.0,   "  High",                                   minval = 0)
i_err_man_low               = input(10.0,   "  Low",                                    minval = 0)
i_err_man_close             = input(10.0,   "  Close",                                  minval = 0)
// }

plot(close)
```

The input section of the [example script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/) is this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4
//@author=LucF

// Delta Volume Columns Pro [LucF]
//  v1.2, 2020.04.03 10:22 — LucF

// This indicator plots either delta volume columns or a volume balance line.

// This code was written using the following standards:
//  • PineCoders Coding Conventions for Pine: http://www.pinecoders.com/coding_conventions/
//  • A modified version of the PineCoders 16-Color Gradient Framework: https://www.tradingview.com/script/EjLGV9qg-Color-Gradient-16-colors-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/
//  • A modified version of the PineCoders MTF Selection Framework: https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/

// Part of this code is borrowed from a comment by Kuan to a BacktestRookies presentation of an intrabar delta volume indicator here: https://backtest-rookies.com/2019/02/15/tradingview-volume-profile-with-lower-time-frame-data/

// My indicator displaying "Delta Volume Candles" using the same method of calculation is here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/h0yZPTiS-Delta-Volume-Candles-LucF/
// A simpler version of this indicator is my "Delta Volume Columns": https://www.tradingview.com/script/YFBNr8I6-Delta-Volume-Columns-LucF/
// This indicator's page on TV: https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/

study("Delta Volume Columns Pro [LucF]", "PlayGround2")


// ———————————————————— Inputs
// {
DM0 = "Hide Columns", DM1 = "Show Columns"
ON0 = "Hide", ON1 = "Show", ON2 = "Combined Balances — Six-state Dual Color Gradient", ON3 = "Combined Balances — Dual Solid Colors (All Bull/All Bear Only)"
C00 = "None", C01 = "Aqua", C02 = "Black", C03 = "Blue", C04 = "Coral", C05 = "Gold", C06 = "Gray", C07 = "Green", C08 = "Lime", C09 = "Maroon", C10 = "Orange", C11 = "Pink", C12 = "Red", C13 = "Violet", C14 = "Yellow", C15 = "White"
CB0 = "Hide", CB1 = "Volume Balance On Bar", CB2 = "Volume Balance Averages", CB3 = "Volume Balance Momentum", CB4 = "Markers Bias", CB5 = "Dual Buy/Sell Averages", CB6 = "Combined Volume Balances"
CC0 = "None", CC1 = "Buy/Sell Ratio on Bar — Single Color Gradient", CC2 = "Volume Balance on Bar — Dual Color Gradient", CC3 = "Volume Balance Averages — Dual Color Gradient", CC4 = "Volume Balance Momentum — Dual Color Gradient"
CC5 = "Marker Bias — Dual Color Gradient", CC6 = "Buy/Sell Ratio on Bar — Single color, 2 tones", CC7 = "Buy/Sell Ratio on Bar — Dual Solid Colors", CC8 = "Combined Volume Balances — Dual Color Gradient"
TF1 = "Fast, Longer history, Auto-Steps (1min, 5min, 60min, 1D)", TF2 = "More Precise, Shorter History Auto-Steps (1min, 30min, 1D)", TF3 = "Fixed"
MD1 = "Both", MD2 = "Longs Only", MD3 = "Shorts Only"

_10                 = input(true,   "════════════ Columns ═════════════")
columnsMode         = input(DM0,    "Mode",                                     options = [DM0, DM1])
columnsTopColorMode = input(CC6,    "Top Columns Color",                        options = [CC6, CC7, CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5])
columnsBotColorMode = input(CC6,    "Bottom Columns Color",                     options = [CC6, CC7, CC1, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5])
columnsColorB       = input(C07,    "Bull Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
columnsColorS       = input(C09,    "Bear Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
columnsColorN       = input(C14,    "Neutral Color",                            options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
columnsBrite        = input(16,     "Brightness (1-16)",                        minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
_15                 = input(true,   "═════════════ Line ═══════════════")
balanceLine         = input(CB2,    "Mode",                                     options = [CB0, CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4, CB5, CB6])
balanceLineMode     = input(CB1,    "Line Color",                               options = [CB0, CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4, CB6])
balanceLineColorB   = input(C15,    "  Bull Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
balanceLineColorS   = input(C01,    "  Bear Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
balanceLineColorN   = input(C14,    "  Neutral Color",                          options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
balanceLineBrite    = input(16,     "  Brightness",                             minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
balanceLineThick    = input(1,      "  Thickness",                              minval  = 1, maxval = 16)
balanceFillMode     = input(CC4,    "Fill Color",                               options = [CC0, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5])
balanceFillColorB   = input(C05,    "  Bull Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
balanceFillColorS   = input(C13,    "  Bear Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
balanceFillBrite    = input(16,     "  Brightness",                             minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
_18                 = input(true,   "═══════════ Zero Line ═════════════")
zeroLineColorMode   = input(ON2,    "Mode",                                     options = [ON0, ON2, ON3])
zeroLineColorB      = input(C08,    "  Bull Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
zeroLineColorS      = input(C12,    "  Bear Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
zeroLineBrite       = input(16,     "  Brightness",                             minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
zeroLineThickness   = input(1,      "  Thickness",                              minval  = 0)
_20                 = input(true,   "═══════════ Divergences ════════════")
divergenceMode      = input(CB0,    "Mode",                                     options = [CB0, CB1, CB2, CB3, CB6])
divergenceColor     = input(C10,    "  Color",                                  options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
divergenceBrite     = input(10,     "  Brightness",                             minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
divergenceVolN      = input(false,  "Consider Neutral Volume a Divergence")
colordivLevelsMode  = input(ON1,    "Divergence Levels",                        options = [ON0, ON1])
colordivLevelsBull  = input(C07,    "  Bull Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
colordivLevelsBear  = input(C09,    "  Bear Color",                             options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
colordivLevelsNeut  = input(C06,    "  Neutral Color",                          options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
divLevelsBrite      = input(10,     "  Brightness",                             minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
filldivLevels       = input(false,  "Fill Levels")
divLevelsFillBrite  = input(6,      "    Brightness",                           minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
_30                 = input(true,   "═══════════ Background ════════════")
backgdFillMode      = input(CC5,    "Fill Color",                               options = [CC0, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5])
backgdColorB        = input(C06,    "Bull Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
backgdColorS        = input(C03,    "Bear Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
backgdFillBrite     = input(16,     "Brightness",                               minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
_35                 = input(true,   "═══════════ Chart Bars ═════════════")
chartbFillMode      = input(CC4,    "Mode",                                     options = [CC0, CC7, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5])
chartbColorB        = input(C15,    "Bull Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
chartbColorS        = input(C01,    "Bear Color",                               options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
chartbFillBrite     = input(16,     "Brightness",                               minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
hollowOutBodies     = input(false,  "Empty bodies on decreasing volume")
_40                 = input(true,   "════════ Intrabar Resolution ══════════")
itfType             = input(TF1,    "Selection",                                options = [TF1, TF2, TF3])
itfTypeFixedRes     = input("15",   "  Fixed Resolution",                       type    = input.resolution)
itfShow             = input(true,   "Show Resolution")
offsetLabels        = input(3,      "  Label Horizontal Offset")
_45                 = input(true,   "══════ Total Volume Discrepancies ═══════")
bgColor             = input(C00,    "Background Color",                         options = [C00, C01, C02, C03, C04, C05, C06, C07, C08, C09, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15])
bgBrightness        = input(1,      "Background Brightness",                    minval  = 1, maxval = 16) * 0.625
failureTolerance    = input(1.,     "Failure Tolerance (%)",                    minval  = 0., maxval = 50., step = 0.25) / 100
showRealtime        = input(false,  "Show Realtime volume")
_50                 = input(true,   "════════════ Markers ═════════════")
markerDirection     = input(MD1,    "Direction",                                options = [MD1, MD2, MD3])
showMarker1         = input(false,  "Marker 1: Combined Balances Agreement")
showMarker2         = input(false,  "Marker 2: Double Bumps")
showMarker3         = input(false,  "Marker 3: Divergence Confirmations")
marker3Mode         = input(CB1,    "  Using...",                               options = [CB1, CB2, CB3, CB6])
showMarker4         = input(false,  "Marker 4: Volume Balance Shifts")
marker4Mode         = input(CB2,    "  Using...",                               options = [CB2, CB3, CB6])
showMarker5         = input(false,  "Marker 5: Markers Bias Shifts")
_55                 = input(true,   "════════════ Periods ══════════════")
balAvgPeriod        = input(100,    "Volume Balance Averages Period",           minval  = 2)
balMomPeriod        = input(14,     "Volume Balance Momentum Period",           minval  = 2)
biasPeriod          = input(14,     "Markers Bias Period",                      minval  = 2)
buySellMasPeriod    = input(50,     "Dual Buy/Sell Averages Period",            minval  = 2)

var longsOnly       = markerDirection == MD2
var shortsOnly      = markerDirection == MD3
// }

plot(close)
```

Here's a screenshot of the difference between the [example script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/) (on the left) and my script (on the right):

[image: Input alignment screenshot]

So the question is how to get my inputs to be right-aligned like in the [example script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/)?

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the text and the widgets is controlled by the longest text you are using. Once you have a stable maximum distance established with a long text legend, then you can do step 2, which is to manually calibrate the "═" characters in your headers so they align correctly with the end of the widgets. Their quantity will need to vary with the text in the header as the font used is not monospaced.

Once that's done, if you don't want to have to redo all the "═" calibration, all the next legends you add with new `input()`'s need to be shorter than your previous longest )